# Class 'Services_Twilio' not found

Tags: twilio

I am using Laravel 4 version and using Twilio for sending messages. I have installed Twilio/SDK through composer. I am using the below code in helper.php

```
    $client = new \Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    try {
        $message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
            "From" => $twillo_number,
            "To" => $phone,
            "Body" => $message,
        ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //Log::error($e->getMessage());
    }
```

I always getting an error on my screen which is 
*Class 'Services_Twilio' not found*

Can you help on this? Why is this issue coming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

My guess here is that you have installed the Twilio PHP SDK version 5, but you are following a tutorial that was written for version 4.

To [send a message with the latest version of the Twilio SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), you can use this code:

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid = "your_account_sid";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

try {
    $client->messages->create(
        $phone,
        array(
            'from' => $twilio_number,
            'body' => $message
        )
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Log::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Also, you can check the documentation for the most up to date way to [send a message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages).

Let me know if that helps at all.